# Перезагрузка страницы

Tags: javascript

Как перезагрузить страницу с отправкой формы на ява скрипте? По нажатию радио кнопки перезагрузить страницу и отправить в пост данных только данные кнопки...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $.post('url', {'data': value}, function(){
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Жуквери. Если надо, могу и просто javascript'ом написать.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Добавить"/>
</form>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
try
{
document.forms[0].submit();
} catch(e) {}
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: работает, но только нужно отправить не всю форму а только ее часть

в данный момент реализовано криво

    document.getElementById('e2').value='';
    document.getElementById('s1').selectedIndex='0';
    document.getElementById('s2').selectedIndex='0';
    document.getElementById('s3').selectedIndex='0';
    document.getElementById('s4').selectedIndex='0';
    document.forms["mf1"].submit();

а отправке подлежат только 4 радио кнопки.
как переделать так чтобы именно отправить запрос а не нажать кнопку отправки формы?)

Comment: Перед отправкой формы, делайте disabled ненужные радиокнопки, форма их не отправит.

И потом Радио кнопки всегда отправляют только одно значение. А чекбоксы несколько.

Answer (score 0):

Странная задача, для чего такое может понадобиться, если не секрет?

Вижу 2 решения:

1. разбить форму на несколько форм
2. использовать ajax в виде jquery.post, собирая нужные данные из формы ([Jquery.POST](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2FjQuery.post%2F&ei=npBRTrz8A4PXsgbA5tnHAw&usg=AFQjCNHwpa0KUYZqVvVwXY5sIVnyWHgTTg))

Comment: Изменение языка страници и бд к которой она подконекчена, т.е. остается радио кнопка языка, радио кнопка вида сортировки.

пы.сы оставил как было)